# Animate window in and out jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-maps-api-3

I created a toggle switch in jQuery. If you click on a marker, a sidebar is sliding inside the screen, and when you click the same marker, it slides back. But, I have multiple markers on my screen, and if you click another marker, the animation continues to slide inside, so the sidebar is getting bigger. What I want is that when you click any marker, that the sidebar is staying the same size, but I cannot achieve it with what I tried myself. The code:

```
   google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function() {
                infowindow.open(map,marker);

                if(windowOpen)
                {

                    sidebar.animate({ 
                        width: "-=300px" 
                    }, 500, function()
                    {
                        console.log('complete');
                    });


                 windowOpen = false;

                }
                else
                {
                    sidebar.animate({ 
                        width: "+=300px" 
                    }, 500, function()
                    {



                    });

                    windowOpen = true;
                }



              });
```

Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Many thanks!

Comment: so you click Marker A, and the sidebar opens.  You want it so that if you click Marker B, the sidebar remains open at the same size.  But if you then click either Marker A or Marker B again, the sidebar then closes?

Comment: Almost! It indeed opens and closes if I click on Marker A. If I click on Marker A it opens, but if I click on Marker B it opens again. I want it indeed to have the same size.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you haven't defined `windowOpen` outside of the eventHandler. Thus, on every click windowOpen is undefined leading to your `else` code being executed. Try this:

```
var windowOpen = false;

google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function() {
  // your code
}
```

Comment: It is working, I did declare the windowOpen var, (sorry i didnt copy it). The animation is working when clicking on one of the markers. It is animating back when it is active, but only for the clicked marker. If i click another marker the animation is animating the other way round again, so the sidebar's width increases again, but I want to animate it back even when you click on other markers.